# Synchronizing local time with databaser server time

Tags: sql, windows, delphi, firebird

I have to synchronize my local date and time with the same date and time returned from the database.

The sql:

```
select first 1 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from RDB$DATABASE
```

This SQL command returns the current date and time at the database server.

Now, I need to cache this and provide the correct time based on the local diff.
The problem is that the local date and time can be changed again.

How can I do this to garantee the correct date time without execute the SQL again?

---

I found a solution:

```
var
  SQLTimestamp: TDateTime=0;
  LocalTimestamp: TDateTime=0;

function SysUpTime : TDateTime;
var
  Count, Freq : int64;
begin
  QueryPerformanceCounter(count);
  QueryPerformanceFrequency(Freq);
  if (count<> 0) and (Freq <> 0) then
  begin
    Result := Count / Freq;
    Result := result / SecsPerDay;
  end
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

function RealTime: TDateTime;
var
  queryTime, dbTime: tdatetime;
begin
  if SQLTimestamp = 0 then
  begin
    queryTime := SysUpTime;
    dbTime := // SQL QUERY EXECUTION
    queryTime := SysUpTime - queryTime;

    LocalTimestamp := SysUpTime;
    SQLTimestamp := dbTime + queryTime;
  end;

  Result := SQLTimestamp + (SysUpTime - LocalTimestamp);
end;
```

**Now my question is**: [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has the same limitation as [GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)?

```
 The elapsed time is stored as a DWORD value. Therefore, the time will wrap around to zero if the system is run continuously for 49.7 days.
```

Comment: First, you can't. Time keeps ticking, so the client needs to read it directly. Second, on Vista and higher (or XP when running as a non-power user), changing the system date or time requires administrator privileges.

Comment: To add to the other comments... you can never find out what the time IS, only what it WAS.  There are tools like NTP to take care of this problem, which was solved long ago.

Comment: I don't want to CHANGE the OS datetime, I only want to have a short-hand to query for the database datetime, assuming what that time  (in database) will never be changed.

Comment: You've asked two **entirely** different questions. Do you want to know how to avoid asking the server what time it is? Or do you want to know the limitations of QueryPerformanceCounter? Please edit your question to ask just **one** question. Remember that you're allowed to post an unlimited number of separate questions, and that you're *encouraged* to do so when your separate questions do not relate to each other, as is the case here.

Comment: which precision do you want from your function?

Comment: just re-execute the query if the local time had changed and update your cache.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms725498.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does any cache do ? It gives you a ready-made result if some defining conditions still hold, or re-query/re-calculate result if they changed.

That is what you cache have to do as well. Just re-execute the query if the local time was overrode and use the cache while it is continuous.

Do re-execute the query, just do it only when you need it rather than on every attempt. http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms725498.aspx

Now what i'd really like to know what would you do if the server's clock would be changed, not the local one. Maybe you'd really install separate time-syncing service along wit hdatabase server?

Comment: I changed my implementation to use the WM_TIMECHANGE to re-cache the time values and now I'm using the "now" function. The database server date time will never change, this is a premise I assume (I know this can cause problems)! Thanks Arioch

Comment: Windows has a number of notifications "this or that changed and u're not to assume the context you knew before", it is not only about time :-)

Comment: If anything, the server can have daemon running, only to monitor it's own time change, to user FB's POST_EVENT to notify clients of the change.